# ASP dropdownlist with same key but different value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, html-select

I would like to know how can I get the dropdownlist to have the same key but different value. You can find the values I want to include in the dropdownlist at the image below:

[image]

Is that doable at all?

Comment: Isn't the point of the key it being unique?

Comment: This isn't possible, but it also appears to me that both `OperationNo` values of `10` would not generally need to be in the drop down at the same time.

Comment: The description is unique, I did the other way around, key => description, value => operationno and it works now as it should be. Thanks

Comment: you can use any other control, like a grid or something else or data list

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the same *value* but different *text*?

Something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="1">Third</option>
</select>
```

If that's the case, then I don't believe you can do that.  Even if you were to craft the HTML manually instead of using the server-side `DropDownList` control, how would you discern the `value` when the form is submitted?

The whole point of the `value` in a `select` (or the "key" in any dictionary) is to be unique.  This unique value should be something the system uses to determine the, well, unique option being selected.

You can *display* non-unique things in the text to make them look like keys, something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1 - First</option>
    <option value="2">2 - Second</option>
    <option value="3">1 - Third</option>
</select>
```

That's because the text is unimportant.  The system uses the `value` to determine which `option` is selected.

Comment: If he never needs to know what description was selected, only the operation number, then why not have duplicate values in the options?  I see what you're saying but afaik there is nothing that actually prevents him from doing this with HTML as you've pointed out.

Comment: @mikey: I suppose in that case it's worth trying. If it doesn't work then as a last resort he can always use any dummy value for the `value` (an incrementing integer) and concatenate the two data elements into the text, then just parse out the desired data element on the server from the selected text. If duplicate values don't work, that is. Checking the HTML spec now, I haven't found an explicit statement that the values in `option` tags need to be unique for a given `select`. However, I personally wouldn't trust it. There's a chance that behavior may be undefined across different browsers.

Comment: I've always thought of an HTML select as a more rigid text input, basically the option that is selected sets its value.  When you look at the form value by the select's name on the POST target end, only the value of the selected option is passed, not the text for it or any of the other options.  I do agree though having dupe values is not ideal because inevitably someone comes along complaining that when they revisit the page the item they originally selected is no longer selected i.e. the need to know *which* option was selected always seems to arise ;)